# Stop execution of function if user clicks on a div in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user loads a page, I trigger a "timer" that will show the message after 8 seconds.
My problem is that I would like to prevent the message to be displayed in case the user clicks on the div #contentAfterIntro before those 8 seconds.

```
xoxo();
function xoxo(e) {
   setTimeout(showMessage, 8000);
   $("#contentAfterIntro").on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
}

function showMessage() {   
    $('#msg').addClass('visible');
    console.log('show msg');
  }
```

The code above does not work. In my tests, even if I click before the 8 seconds, the messages gets displayed.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns an id which you can use to cancel the timeout:

```
xoxo();
function xoxo(e) {
   var id = setTimeout(showMessage, 8000);
   $("#contentAfterIntro").on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     clearTimeout(id); // <--- clear timeout
   });
}

function showMessage() {   
    $('#msg').addClass('visible');
    console.log('show msg');
}
```

Comment: I'll try now. Do I still need the  e.stopPropagation() if I use the cleartimeout(id) ?

Comment: `stopPropagation` has nothing to do with the timeout, just with the click event. If it was only there to try to stop the timeout, then you do not need it.

Comment: will accept in 10min as SO is blocking me from doing it right now:)